# Trouble Downloading R version 4.0.0

Tags: r, bash, ubuntu, cran

I am trying to download R v4.0.0 to troubleshoot. In attempting to download this github project https://github.com/tipresias/bird-signs the command `$ docker-compose up --build` returns the error "packages ‘TRUE’, ‘FALSE’ are not available (for R version 4.0.0) ".

Thus I decided to try an downgrade to R version 4.0.0 (I had some version higher though it is uninstalled now so I can no longer check). I tried `$ sudo apt-get install r-base-core=4.0.0-1.2004.0` but that returned the error "Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages." I've checked for broken packages through `$ dpkg --get-selections | grep hold` which showed nothing so confused as to how the previous command didn't work as I don't hold broken packages (confirmed by synaptic package manager).

I tried downloading R 4.0.0 through CRAN (https://cran.curtin.edu.au/) but the command `$ ./configure` returns the error "configure: error: --with-x=yes (default) and X11 headers/libs are not available" I tried `$ apt-get install libx11-dev` but the error persists and can't locate the files with `$ locate X11/extensions/XInput.h`.

I am on Ubuntu 22.04.2 'jammy' and have an AMD graphics card.

Sorry if these questions are rudimentary, I'm new to this world.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :D

Comment: Try `docker pull r-base:4.0.3` to get the final version of the 4.0.* series.  You should be able to get all others too.  (I maintain the underlying Dockerfille, it is also `rocker-org/r-base:*` for all tags.)

Comment: I ran the code `docker pull r-base:4.0.3` and it yielded the result "4.0.3: Pulling from library/r-base
Digest: sha256:497d5e9fcd96981b07da6c118bc97a6998a67e3d67c14b4df0332c0e5d7662f8
Status: Image is up to date for r-base:4.0.3
docker.io/library/r-base:4.0.3"
Which I think means it worked but when I run `R --version` it says "command R not found". Original problem with `docker-compose up --build` still persists .

Comment: So it said you have working image. Try `docker run --rm -ti r-base:4.0.3 Rscript --version` and you should see one line stating that version.